# How can I disable/enable (on/off) the swipe in the slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I need a zoom feature inside every slide, so I installed a zoom app (http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom) in them. But I want to freeze momentarily or disable the swipe when the user is dragging the mouse or touching to see other areas of the image.

The zoom app has functions onZoomIn and onZoomOut that I can add a trigger to an event or anything else, but I could not figure out how to disable the slick carousel.

I know there are many carousels apps, and I would accept suggestions, but I need to use slick, because slick is the only one I tried that didn't change the elements drastically, like stretching or shrinking unless desirable.

So, is there a way disable the dragging on slick?